# Возможно ли подобное цитирование?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Возможно ли цитирование в предложении? А в каких случаях подобное цитирование будет считаться ошибкой?

> Художник И.С. Остроухов собирал иконы и произведения живописи, его
> коллекция впоследствии стала основой открытого «Музея иконописи и
> живописи имени И.С. Остроухова».